The container don't reflects what was executed from Dockerfile
I'm wondering if something is missing in my configuration?. Each time I recreate containers, everything seems to be correct. However, after creating and logging into the container, none of the listed commands are executed. I'd really like to know if someone has experienced the same behavior. If you noted that some configuration have been duplicated it's because docker-compose is the only one is 'hearing' the commands I listed.
Thanks in advance for any suggestions.
Execution log:
Step 1/12 : FROM python:3.8
 ---> b22191dc7e28
Step 2/12 : WORKDIR /packages
 ---> Running in 9a44c91d145b
Removing intermediate container 9a44c91d145b
 ---> 0478566f6412
Step 3/12 : RUN apt-get update && apt-get -y install python3 python3-pip cron
 ---> Running in aeba3575d3b4
Get:1 http://deb.debian.org/debian bookworm InRelease [151 kB]
Get:2 http://deb.debian.org/debian bookworm-updates InRelease [55.4 kB]
Get:3 http://deb.debian.org/debian-security bookworm-security InRelease [48.0 kB]
Get:4 http://deb.debian.org/debian bookworm/main amd64 Packages [8786 kB]
Get:5 http://deb.debian.org/debian bookworm-updates/main amd64 Packages [12.7 kB]
Get:6 http://deb.debian.org/debian-security bookworm-security/main amd64 Packages [154 kB]
Fetched 9207 kB in 2s (3777 kB/s)
Reading package lists...
Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...
python3 is already the newest version (3.11.2-1+b1).

Within container:
root@123430e848ee:/# python3 --version
bash: python3: command not found
root@123430e848ee:/# python --version
bash: python: command not found

docker-compose.yml:
version: '3.1'

services:
  db:
    image: mariadb:10.5
    container_name: mariadb
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
      MYSQL_USER: root
      MYSQL_DATABASE: mariadb
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    volumes:
      - ./src:/packages
      - ./populate-db:/populate-db
      - ./startup.sh:/packages/startup.sh
      - ./requirements.txt:/packages/requirements.txt
    networks:
      - mariadbnet

  phpmyadmin:
    image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
    container_name: phpmyadmin
    ports:
      - "8080:80"
    depends_on:
      - db
    environment:
      PMA_ARBITRARY: 1
      PMA_HOST: db
    networks:
      - mariadbnet

  populate-db:
    build:
      context: ./populate-db
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - ./populate-db:/populate-db
    depends_on:
      - db
    networks:
      - mariadbnet

  packages:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - ./src:/packages
      - ./startup.sh:/packages/startup.sh
      - ./requirements.txt:/packages/requirements.txt
    depends_on:
      - db
      - populate-db
    networks:
      - mariadbnet
    command: sh -c "sleep 10 && ./packages/startup.sh"

networks:
  mariadbnet:
    driver: bridge

Dockerfile:
FROM python:3.8

WORKDIR /packages

# Install Python 3 and pip
RUN apt-get update && apt-get -y install python3 python3-pip cron

# Install dependencies
COPY requirements.txt /packages/requirements.txt

# Install dependencies
RUN pip3 install --no-cache-dir -r /packages/requirements.txt

# Golden Package Update script
COPY /src/copy_run_sql.py /packages/copy_run_sql.py

# Following crontab execution
RUN touch /var/log/cron_packages.log
RUN touch /var/log/packages.log

# Startup script
COPY startup.sh /packages/startup.sh
RUN chmod +x /packages/startup.sh

# Run cron job
RUN echo "0 * * * * root /usr/bin/nohup /usr/bin/python3 /packages/copy_run_sql.py > /var/log/cron_packages.log 2>&1
&" >> /etc/crontab

CMD ["/bin/bash","-c","/packages/startup.sh"]

Expected results:
root@123430e848ee:/# apt-get update && apt-get -y install python3 python3-pip cron
Reading state information... Done
cron is already the newest version (3.0pl1-136ubuntu1).
python3 is already the newest version (3.8.2-0ubuntu2).
python3-pip is already the newest version (20.0.2-5ubuntu1.10).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1 not upgraded.


"logging into the container" - please show us how you doing this (e.g. docker compose packages /bin/bash? The fact that the prompt does not include /packages makes me think you are not in the expected container. Could you please minimise your example (remove the other containers from your compose file and limit the Dockerfile to what is necessary to replicate the issue - it's easier to help if we can try to build your environment).

(The python image already contains Python and Pip, and I don't think it's installed using APT.  You don't need the apt-get install lines you show.)
